# SqlDataReader doesn't show return rows even when stored procedure does

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to get data using a `SqlDataReader`. When I look at the result, I do see the number of columns but rows are missing and I am seeing only blanks with "the enumeration yielded no results".

After spending much time and going through similar issues on the net I couldn't resolve my issue. Then I tried the same stored procedure but used the DataAdapter. Using a `DataAdapter`, all the rows were returned. I am not sure what is causing the issue. I tried to rewrite my methods differently but no avail.

```
public static SqlDataReader ExecuteDataReader(string connection, string storedProcedure)  
{       
    using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        //  sqlCon.Open();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, sqlCon)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };


        sqlCon.Open();

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var count = reader.FieldCount;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(i));
                    }
            }
        }

        //reader.Close();
        return null;  // for testing purpose
    }
}
```

--stored procedure.  (kept it simple)

```
Create PROC [dbo].GetTheData  

As   

select     '1' AS one,'2' as two,'3' as three,'4' as four,'5'as five
```

Comment: You used the same `AddWithValue` with the DataAdapter? Why you pass a string for a numeric value?

Comment: DataAdapter uses ExecuteReader itself. There is **no** other way to retrieve rows. DataAdapter doesn't *read* anything from the database. It reads the results produced from a DbDataReader into a DataTable. If you get different results, it's because you are executing different code, with different parameters.

Comment: A DataReader can actually return multiple resultsets, and perhaps you are getting an empty resultset first.  See [SqlDataReader.NextResult()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: For performance gain I want to use the sql data reader. and I made sure there is no two result sets my stored procedure return.

Comment: Use Sql Server Profiler to debug your problem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/start-sql-server-profiler